# Error: Uncaught (in promise): PushNotifications does not have web implementation

Tags: angular, push-notification, ionic4, capacitor, ionic5

How to catch this exception for web implementation, or to proceed with Push Notification for web.

If anyone can help me with it, it will be very helpful. ☺

Code that I have implemented:

```js
PushNotifications.addListener('registrationError', (error: any) => {
    console.log('Error on registration: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
});

PushNotifications.addListener('pushNotificationReceived', (notification: PushNotification) => {
    console.log('Push received: ' 
        + JSON.stringify(notification.data));

    this.openToast(notification.data);
});

PushNotifications.addListener('pushNotificationActionPerformed', (notification: PushNotificationActionPerformed) => {
    console.log('Push action performed: ' 
        + JSON.stringify(notification.notification.data));

    this.navigate.navigateForward([
        'profile',
        notification.notification.data.identification,
    ]);
});
```

Just wanted to know how to implement `PushNotification` for web in `ionic using capacitor`. if there is any plugin or atleast if I can handle this exception.

Please let me know, in case of any further clarification

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61666423/2039326, i.e. the below answer fixed my problem no need to catch exception

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can add this check before initializing your push notifications..

```js
import { Capacitor } from '@capacitor/core';
     
const isPushNotificationsAvailable = Capacitor.isPluginAvailable('PushNotifications');
     
if (isPushNotificationsAvailable) {
     this.initPushNotifications();
}
```

Comment: Okay, will check and let you know. Hopefully this will work. Thanks for the answer, on confirmation I will mark this as solution answer. Thanks again.